# UIView frame not updating in viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm using `Storyboard` with `autolayout`. In my `ViewController` I have a basic structure: one `UIScrollView` and one contentView (`UIView`) that contains different labels). Then I have different elements that I add in the `viewDidAppear` method of the class inside my `contentView` , then in order to recalculate it's frame size I do this:

```
- (void)fixContentViewHeight 
{
    _contentView.frame = CGRectMake(_contentView.frame.origin.x, _contentView.frame.origin.y, _contentView.frame.size.width, operators.frame.origin.y + operators.frame.size.height);
     //constraint for contentView height
    _contentViewHeight.constant = operators.frame.origin.y + operators.frame.size.height;
}

- (void)fixScrollViewHeight 
{
    _scrollView.frame = _contentView.frame;
    _scrollView.contentSize = _contentView.frame.size;
}
```

where `operators` is the LAST placed element of `contentView`, it's always on the bottom of the frame. I call these 2 methods inside the `viewDidAppear` and they make the view scrollable, the problem is that the frame of `contentView` doesn't get updated so the last elements are always unclickable (because they're placed outside the frame of the view).

What am I doing wrong? Why the `scrollView` becomes scrollable but the `contentView` keeps it's old frame?

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: @NickCatib yes I'm using autolayout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have autolayout constraints affecting the height of `_contentView` You will not be able to change its height by setting the frame, as the constraints will override that.

You will need to (and should be) adding new / modifying constraints in your code when you are adding new elements. then calling

```
_contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

After all the updates to let the UI update if it needs to, which it should.

Comment: I've tried using a height constraint in my contentView, I update it like this as in the code posted above:

    `_contentViewHeight.constant = operators.frame.origin.y + operators.frame.size.height;`
The value I assing is correct but the height doesn't change at all. If I call `[_contentView layoutIfNeeded]` the `scrollView` becomes unscrollable

Comment: @Signo 1. You can't set the frame height and the height constraint. These are conflicting. 2. You should try let autolayout do all this work for you, rather than computing the height manually, ask autolayout to compute for you, using top / bottom constraints on all the items. 3. When you using `layoutIfNeeded` did the _contentView expand correctly? 4. Are there constraints from the content view to the top of the scrollview and from bottom to bottom? 5. Did you try calling `layoutIfNeeded` on both views?

Comment: I got it working! after reading point 4 I've checked again my constraints in IB and there were 2 conflicting constraint. I've cleared the constraints from `contentView` and now it's working fine, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Please update UI On Main Queue

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // update any UI on Main queue
        });
```

Comment: Based on the info provided, this is not going to help, OP has stated the scrollview is updating, so that is clearly fine. OP has also not mentioned any background tasks.

Answer (score 1):

I think that all your frame related information should be inside `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`. You can add stuff in `viewDidLoad()` but for any frame management I would use mentioned methods.

In your particular situation use former, `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`. However, you can resolve these kind of issues using constraints connected to the code as @Simon McLoughlin mentioned. 'scrollView becomes unscrollable' means that you should update `contentSize` as well so keep an eye on that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add vertical space constraint between scroll view and your last placed element.